# Append Directory on ubuntu using python

Tags: python, ubuntu, directory

I want to get the current file's directory, but by `os.path.abspath(__file__)`, I can only get something like `/home/gmarth/Documents/pythonLearning.py`, yet I want to remove the file name, left file's path like `/home/gmarth/Documents`. I achieved this on Windows with the following code:

```
current = str(os.path.abspath(__file__))
for itera in range(len(current) - 1, 0, -1):
    if current[itera] == '\\':
        dir = current[0: itera]
        break;
self._path = dir
```

But on ubuntu, nearly the same code doesn't work:

```
current = str(os.path.abspath(__file__))
for itera in range(len(current)-1, 0, -1):
    if current[itera] == '/':       #only changed here
        directory = current[0: itera]
        break;
self._path = dierctory
```

I got:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'directory' referenced before assignment
```

That confused me, I don't have much experiences on ubnuntu, how can I get the similar result like Windows?

P.S. (Don;t know if that matters) On windows I built it a project; while on Ubuntu it's a single `.py` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more portable alternative:

```
self._path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

[`dirname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) replaces your loop

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on my ubuntu. (minus the typo at the end)

The error mean that you never used a variable named "directory" before trying to put it in _path, i.e. you never went in the if (which is weird since you should at least hit the root at some point)